# How to show original feature names in the feature importance plot?

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I created XGBoost model as follows:

```
y = XY.DELAY_MIN
X = standardized_df

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X.as_matrix(), y.as_matrix(), test_size=0.25)

my_imputer = preprocessing.Imputer()
train_X = my_imputer.fit_transform(train_X)
test_X = my_imputer.transform(test_X)

xgb_model = XGBRegressor()

# Add silent=True to avoid printing out updates with each cycle
xgb_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, learning_rate=0.05)
xgb_model.fit(train_X, train_y, early_stopping_rounds=5, 
             eval_set=[(test_X, test_y)], verbose=False)
```

When I create the feature importance plot, the feature names are shown as "f1", "f2", etc. How can I show original feature names?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,18))
xgb.plot_importance(xgb_model, max_num_features=30, height=0.8, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `Imputer` doesn't return a `pd.DataFrame` as an output of `transform()`, thus, your column names get lost, when you do

```
train_X = my_imputer.fit_transform(train_X)
test_X = my_imputer.transform(test_X)
```

Simple solution, wrap the imputer output into a dataframe, for example like this:

```
train_X = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(train_X), columns=train_X.columns)
test_X  = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(test_X), columns=test_X.columns)
```